# How do I separate my data based on angle oscillation?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, intervals, logical-operators

I have a dataset structured like below.

| Elapsed Time (sec) | Vertical Translation (cm) | Gantry Angle (deg) | TreatmentDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 343.367 | 0.0454447 | 181.00000 | Nov 2 |
| 344.065 | 0.0523568 | 184.46055 | Nov 2 |
| 344.766 | 0.0136066 | 187.92109 | Nov 2 |
| 345.470 | 0.0287900 | 191.38164 | Nov 2 |

The angle essentially oscillates from 181 to 270, then from 90 to 180 back to 90, then from 270 to 181 within one TreatmentDate factor (there are about 8-10 dates). I'd like to separate the data into 3 clusters to see if each section of oscillation is distributed similarly.

Thus, I would have a dataset like above, but with angles 181 to 270, then another dataset with angles 90-180-90, then another dataset from 270-180.

Thing is, I can't really index them properly because the intervals between Elapsed Time are different for each TreatmentDate (ranging from 0.4 to 0.9 second intervals); I can't make the data collect in equal intervals because it's a system detecting movement and storing a data point whenever it detects a shift.

Also, if I try to subset the data like so: `AdjustedCluster1 <- subset(finalTableAdjusted, 180 < Gantry.Angle..deg. & Gantry.Angle..deg. < 270)`, it doesn't quite separate the data properly (incorporates data that should be in the first cluster, as well as data that should be in the third).

What should I do?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a column `your_data$sign_change = sign(c(0, diff(your_data$Gantry.Angle..deg.)))` that indicates the direction the angle is changing relative the previous row. Then you could subset when `Gantry.Angle..deg.  > 180 & sign_change == "+"` for when it is increasing and similarly by `sign_change == "-"` for when it is decreasing. (Note that this column may need to be calculated "by group" based on the date... I'd recommend using the `dplyr` package for that.)

Comment: The phrases "similarly" and "doesn't quite separate the data properly" seem inadequately defined and the data example is woefully incomplete which could have been reasons to close the question but decided to close as a duplicate of a question with a complete example and a good answer to the task of fitting descriptive parameters to an oscillation with irregular time spacing.

Comment: @GregorThomas That worked! Completely didn't think of that, thank you so much!